# I am getting a error saying that cannot make a static reference to the non-static method GetNUmber() from the type Vehicle

Tags: java

I am getting a error saying that cannot make a static reference to the non-static method GetNUmber() from the type Vehicle.I don't really understand what's happening. Please help!

```
public class Vehicle
{

    private int VehicleNumber;




public void SetNumber (int N){

    VehicleNumber = N;

}

public  int GetNumber (){

    return VehicleNumber;

}


public static void main (String args[]){

    Vehicle Maxda = new Vehicle();
    Maxda.SetNumber(23423);
    System.out.println("Vehicle Maxda number is " + GetNumber());


}   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetNumber()` (which, incidentally, should be named `getNumber()`) is an *instance* method.

This line doesn't make sense:

```
    System.out.println("Vehicle Maxda number is " + GetNumber());
```

You can't call that method without an instance to call it on.

Comment: ok problem solved it should be Maxda.Getnumber() Thanks